# Installing gnuplot/pgfplots on Texshop on Mac

Tags: macos, latex

I need to install a plotting package for my Mactex. What I mainly found is that gnuplot and pgfplots are two main plotting packages for this purpose. I was wondering if someone please show me step y step how to install these packages? I have Homebrew and I use Texshop (if relevant). I really appreciate if you make it step by step.
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you installed MaxTex you should already have `pgfplots` installed. You can do a lot of graphs without `gnuplot`, but to install `gnuplot`, I think you need to have the `gcc` installed which you should have if you have `XCode` installed. Also, LaTeX related questions are better posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It works and sorry I posted it in a wrong place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting comment to answer:

If you installed `MaxTex` you should already have `pgfplots` installed. You can do a lot of graphs without `gnuplot`, but to install `gnuplot`, I think you need to have the `gcc` installed which you should have if you have `XCode` installed.

Comment: Thank you! I have XCode installed, can you please let me know how to install gnuplot as well? I have pgfplots and it works; I really appreciate if you let me know how to install gnuplot.

Comment: @Nikandish: You need to have a look at the README/INSTALL files that should be in the `gnuplot` directory that you downloaded. Then going that directory in a unix shell and typing `./configure` followed by `make install` should do it. Of course that requires that you have `gcc` installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it and at the end this is the last part of (log) in terminal:    
    `mkdir: /usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/tex/latex/gnuplot:     Permission denied
    make[3]: *** [install-texDATA] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1`  also, if possible, would you please let me know link to a simple example using gnuplot? I need to learn it very quickly and the best way is to learn it by examples. I am faily new to latex.

Comment: Well from the error messages it appears that you do not have permission to install it, so perhaps do it on an account that has write permissions, or use `sudo`.  I can't give you any better examples than are in the documentation. The `pgfplots` documentation should also have some basic examples, or already available at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Like I said earlier, you don't need to have `gnuplot` to do plots, `pgfplots` is sufficient for many graphs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right. I needed to be root user. Instead I used sudo and it worked. Thanks a lot for your time and patience